# Questions about upgrading scipy via homebrew and how to go about getting a fortran compiler

Tags: python-2.7, gcc, scipy, homebrew, gfortran

I try to run

```
 pip install --upgrade scipy
```

But I get a bunch of errors:

```
   running build_clib

customize UnixCCompiler

customize UnixCCompiler using build_clib

customize Gnu95FCompiler

Could not locate executable gfortran

Could not locate executable f95

customize NAGFCompiler

customize AbsoftFCompiler

Could not locate executable f90

Could not locate executable f77

customize IBMFCompiler

Could not locate executable xlf90

Could not locate executable xlf

customize IntelFCompiler

Could not locate executable ifort

Could not locate executable ifc

customize GnuFCompiler

Could not locate executable g77

customize G95FCompiler

Could not locate executable g95

customize PGroupFCompiler

Could not locate executable pgfortran

don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'

building 'dfftpack' library

error: library dfftpack has Fortran sources but no Fortran compiler found
```

So it looks like I need to install a fortran compiler (don't know if this will solve all my problems). So then I try

```
brew install gcc
```

I then get a warning saying:

```
  gcc-4.9.2_1 already installed, it's just not linked
```

I then try to link it.

```
  brew link gcc
```

But then I get

```
  Error: Could not symlink bin/c++-4.9

 Target /usr/local/bin/c++-4.9
  is a symlink belonging to gcc49. You can unlink it:
  brew unlink gcc49
```

Should I do this? I want gcc49 because I'm on a mac and I use gcc49 to get openmp support (and I if I remember correctly, it gets used when I do any NVIDIA stuff). What are the consequences of unlinking gcc49 and linking gcc?

Answer (score 0):

You should only need `gcc49` if you really need version 4.9 forever.

To get both an OpenMP-compatible gcc and a fortran compiler, you can:

- `brew reinstall gcc49 --with-fortran --without-multilib`, or
- `brew unlink gcc49 && brew install gcc --without-multilib`

You'll have to rebuild the whole gcc collection either way; sorry!

Comment: what does "--without-multilib" do?